# Show only certain curves of multiple layers in graph editor

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm struggling with the animation workflow in Blender. One of my biggest issues is with displaying only relevant curves in the graph editor. So say I want to change the z-location curves of 20 layers. Is there a fast way to display those curves (and only them) or do I have to open and close 20 little triangles and manually click on the eye-symbol of all the x and y location curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly what the **Search** tool is used for.

[image]

**Tip:** You can also filter channels by data types with the **Filter** tool nearby on the same header, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can left click hold and drag to quickly toggle multiple channels.

1. Hold left click and drag all the channels you wish to edit

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to hide x and y, not x, y and z.

Comment: Indeed, I only need Z.